# How do I bind a javascript array to HTML while allowing adding and deleting from the array?

Tags: javascript, html

So the question is how can I keep the HTML elements in sync while I add and delete from an existing array.

If I have an **array of javascript** objects say element 1 is:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    }
    ....
  ]
  .... ETC ETC COMPLICATED ....
}
```

Then my initial html might be generated by using the **array index** for each object of initial size 3 elements [ {}, {}, {} ]:

```
<div id="arrayPos-0">
    <div>John</div>
    <input>PROCESS<input>
    <input>DELETE<input>
</div>
<div id="arrayPos-1">
    <div>Sam</div>
    <input>PROCESS<input>
    <input>DELETE<input>
</div>
<div id="arrayPos-2">
    <div>Timmy</div>
    <input>PROCESS<input>
    <input>DELETE<input>
</div>
```

If I add to the Javascript Array, and I expect to increment it and become [ {}, {}, {}, {} ]:

```
<div id="arrayPos-0">
    ...
</div>
<div id="arrayPos-1">
    ...
</div>
<div id="arrayPos-2">
    ...
</div>
<div id="arrayPos-3">
    <div>Simone</div>
    <input>PROCESS<input>
    <input>DELETE<input>
</div>
```

However as soon as I delete from the javascript array say index 2 (arrayPos-2) I get the following HTML:

```
<div id="arrayPos-0">
    ...
</div>
<div id="arrayPos-1">
    ...
</div>
<div id="arrayPos-3">
    ...
</div>
```

This is all messed up and I'm **unable to match** "arrayPos-3" to now index 2. In addition when I add a new javascript object which is index 3:

```
<div id="arrayPos-0">
    ...
</div>
<div id="arrayPos-1">
    ...
</div>
<div id="arrayPos-3">
    ...
</div>
<div id="arrayPos-3">
    ...
</div>
```

I am not able to use AngularJS and hence ng-repeat can't be used due to support needed on older browsers. It **would** be pretty simple to use an observer to bind the javascript objects directly to the html markup.

I can only use jQuery and regular javascript.
But surely this can be solved in a simpler manner? Do I even need to bind by using IDs? Do I need to autogenerate GUIDs for IDs and use a dictionary to match ID with Javascript object index (I hope not)?

Comment: why do you need these unique id's?

Comment: @yts only using them right now to match an elements DOM with the javascript object inside the array. But that's not working for me since I need to delete and add.

Comment: I'd see this as a data issue. This would be a lot easier if you had a "key" or ID for each person.

Comment: @JonP, why would that make it easier? Why would you care about the ID at all?

Comment: @Shomz, you'd explicitly know what was added and deleted and not have to infer from position. I'm not even saying it is hard with out it. I just prefer explicit vs implicit, probably personal preference there.

Comment: I see, @JonP , I was actually the other way round (I guess because OP mentioned Angular), so as you see in my snippet, I don't care about IDs, just letting the JS data object construct the DOM. Seems like OP only uses those IDs for denoting positions (for a quick access?), so they don't seem as relevant as if they would match each user's internal IDs or something.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to have a generator function which will regenerate the HTML after any changes have been made (adding/deleting/editing).

That way you won't have any confusions with IDs and will always have your current JS object represented in the DOM. That's quite the "Angularish" way to do it - building the DOM from the JS data without really caring what's in the DOM.

Here's a super-simple example to see what I meant:

```js
var data = [
  {name: 'John'},
  {name: 'Shomz'},
  {name: 'Jimmy'}
]

var c = document.getElementById('c');

function build() {
  var output = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    output += '<div id="arrayPos-' + i + '"><button onclick="del(' + i + ')">Del</button><button onclick="edit(' + i + ')">Edit</button>' + data[i].name + '</div>';
  }
  c.innerHTML = output;
}

function del(id) {
  data.splice(id ,1);
  document.getElementById('arrayPos-' + id).className = 'del';
  setTimeout(build, 200);
}

function add() {
  data.push({name: prompt('Enter name')}); 
  build();
}

function edit(id) {
  data[id].name = prompt('Enter name', data[id].name); 
  build();
}

build();
```

```css
#arrayPos-0 {color: green}
button {margin: 4px}
#c div {opacity: 1; transition: all 0.2s linear}
#c div:hover {background: #eee}
#c div.del {opacity: 0}
```

```html
<div id="c"></div>
<br>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery's .attr() method to dynamically set the id property when looping through the objects in the array - if that's the approach you want to take. You could also look at dynamically setting the inner html using JQuery's .html() to set the contents of the divs.  If you review traversing the DOM using JQuery it will help with the latter approach. Hope that helps -

Comment: I agree I can add the ids by using .attr(). However I lose track of the ids to array index when removing an object and adding Another object. The new html ids are messed up by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery .index() method to get the index of the element relative to its siblings. With that, you can match it to the index in the array. No need for adding id's to the elements.

Let's say you already have an index and you want to access the dom element. You can do this:

```
$('.class-name').get(index).remove();
```

Or if you're responding to some event and you're not sure which element in the array it corresponds to, you can do this:

```
$('.class-name').click(function(e){
    var index = $('.class-name').index(e.target);
});
```

In my example I'm using a click event, but it can be any other way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it this way and keep them in order then you caan create a function that:
1.deletes the current divs
2. Re generates the divs in the new order with the corresponding new id's

And just have this function fire every time you add or delete something from the array. It's relatively simple and wont take all that long for javascript to do.

Or:

Create a for loop that loops through the array and identifies which position(number of loops) the object with "x" name is in the array and assigns it to the div.

Answer (score 0):

In-case, if you can modify your existing `js object`, I suggest to use id for both `html element` and the `js object`.

Probably you could go for something:

```
var id = Math.random().toString(16).slice(-6); // for random id, aplha-numeric
```

Your html:

```
<div id="23xc45">
    ...
</div>
<div id="cd567u">
    ...
</div>
```

Your js object:

```
[{
  "id" : "23xc45",
  "firstName": "John",
  ...
},{
  "id" : "cd567u",
  "firstName": "Sam",
  ...
}]
```